# Несколько таблиц и вывод через php переменную

Tags: php, mysql, sql

столкнулся с такой проблемой, выборка идет из 2-х таблиц но надо вывести `id` юзеров через цикл `while`. это я сделал, но там показывается `id` юзера у которого `id` 1, пока не делал выборку из 2-х таблиц `id` работал нормально

```
$q = mysql_query("
   SELECT 
      * 
   FROM users.*, bonus.* 
   ORDER BY users.reputation*10*bonus.ob 
            + money*5*bonus.tb 
            + angel*50*bonus.ab 
   DESC LIMIT ". $start .", ". $max ."");
```

Comment: Это не выборка с 2х таблиц, это набор букофф

Comment: Что запрос по вашему мнению должен возвращать? Покажите на конкретном примере

Answer (score 0):

Нужно указать конкретные столбцы и задать им новые имена, так чтобы они не перезаписывали друг друга

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT 
sers.id as sersId, bonus.id as bonusId, ......
FROM sers, bonus 
ORDER BY users.reputation*10*bonus.ob + money*5*bonus.tb + angel*50*bonus.ab 
DESC LIMIT ". $start .", ". $max ."");
```

Comment: не помогло, всё равно не показывается, а без скобок разве работает?

Answer (score 0):

```
$q = mysql_query("
   SELECT users.* FROM users, 
   LEFT JOIN bonus ON (users.id = bonus.user_id) 
   ORDER BY users.reputation*10*bonus.ob 
            + money*5*bonus.tb 
            + angel*50*bonus.ab 
   DESC LIMIT ". $start .", ". $max ."");
```

Comment: не помогло, всё равно не показывается